# Is it possible for a C program to access and changing a memory address in the heap allocated to another program?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, allocation

Leu us suppose that I have a program like this one (I'll call it program 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
int main(){
    int i;
    int *v;
    v = (int *)malloc (MAX * sizeof (int));

    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        v[i] = i;
    }
    printf("Address:%d\n",&v[0]);
    getchar();

    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        printf("%d\n",v[i]);
    }
}
```

And let us suppose that I have a seconde program (called program 2), like this one:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int address;
    int *v;
    scanf("%d",&address)
    v = address;

    printf("%d\n",*v);
    *v = 100;
}
```

Now, let us suppose that I run program 1 and I collect the address printed by it. The program will be blocked in the getchar() function. And, let us suppose that, while program 1 is blocked, I run program 2 and provide to the scanf the address printed by program 1. Can I access the same memory address allocated to program 1 in program 2?

Best regards.

Comment: Absolutely not (on any modern processor/OS with a memory management unit). Each process is in a seperate address space. Memory can be shared by using explicit mechanisms of the OS such as shared memory. But certainly not in the way you have described.

Answer (score 3):

In an older OS without memory protection (e.g. [AmigaDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaDOS) or [Classic MacOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS)) all processes would run in the same memory-space and you could do tricks like that.  Of course that also meant that any buggy (or malicious) program could easily corrupt other programs, or even crash the entire OS.  So modern OS's give each program its own separate virtual memory space, so even  if your program 2 had the virtual address as printed by program 1, when program 2 tried to dereference that address, it would find that it pointed to a different page of physical memory (or perhaps to no physical page of memory at all, causing a segmentation fault).

Many modern OS's do provide APIs to set up shared memory regions (e.g. [mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) under POSIX) so that multiple programs can access the same physical memory, and some even have APIs to allow you to unilaterally access the private memory of another process (e.g. [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) and [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory) under Windows) but you generally need Administrator access to use those APIs, and they are tricky to use safely, for obvious reasons.